# Is Approval Process supported in Salesforce Lightning?

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience

I have created an approval process for Opportunity object. But I couldn't find the "Submit for Approval" button in Lightning environment when my Opportunity records met the approval process' entry criteria.

I then switched it to Salesforce Classic environment and I'm able to perform the approval process. Am I missing any setting to enable approval process in Lightning environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add **Submit for Approval** button in **Salesforce1 And Lightning Experience Actions** section.

Here is the screen shot.
[image]

[image]

Comment: As of Winter 19' (Sept 2018), that section is now called 'Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions'

Answer (score 3):

You are not missing anything, extra buttons are accessible as an option when you click on down arrow button on right. Refer following screenshot:

[image]